# Equivalence of two approaches for the canonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'm currently studying statistical mechanics. The book the class is following is "*Statistical Mechanics, Third Edition*" of Pathria and Beale. Chapter 3 presents two approaches to canonical ensembles:

1. a more thermodynamical approach, where the ensemble is described by a system with fixed $N$ and $V$ in thermal contact with a reservoir of infinite thermal capacity, so that the temperature is fixed a known value $T = \bar T$;
2. and a more statistic-mechanical approach, where the phase space is constrained by fixing $N$ and $V$, and where $\rho$ is constrained to produce a fixed energy *ensemble average* $\langle H \rangle = E$.

Both approaches give rise to the same probabilities: the first by treating the universe as a micro-canonical system; the second by applying the maximum entropy principle directly. So the book concludes the two approaches are equivalent.

What I do not understand is *why fixing the temperature in the first approach is intuitively equivalent to fixing the average energy in the second approach*?

**PS**: If think the answer should touch the definition of temperature or thermal equilibrium. When I say intuitively I don't mean without doing calculations, I mean without determining that they are the same *a posteriori* like the book did. I'm not an expert so if I did any conceptual mistake please tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view, when you compute the energy of an ideal gas in the classical approximation, you get a one-to-one relation between average energy and temperature,
$$ E=\langle H \rangle= \frac{3}{2} N k_B T. $$
So if you fix the temperature you also fix the average energy of the system and vice versa.

A more intuitive perspective, provided in [Leonard Susskind's lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1RzvXDXyqA&list=PLpGHT1n4-mAsJ123W3fjPzvlDHOvIhHA0), is that the above equation tells you that the temperature is a measure of energy in some "natural units", and the Boltzmann constant can be seen as a sort of conversion factor from these "natural units" to "human units". When you adjust the temperature, you're essentially adjusting the energy per molecule, making the relation average energy-temperature almost tautological.

Comment: I knew this but I don't see any generality in this statement. The ideal gas is pretty special in this sense.

Comment: @HomoVafer The ideal gas is a simple model that precisely allows the kind of intuitive explanations you were asking for. Since the canonical partition function has the structure of a moment-generating function it is completely general that $\langle H\rangle=-\partial_\beta \log(Z)$, with $\beta=1/k_B T$. For fixed volume and number of particles, this means the general one-to-one relation between temperature and average energy.